# How exactly does a ZStack align items within itself?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have the following code

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack (alignment: .bottomTrailing) {
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    .background(.green)
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    .background(.blue)
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .background(.red)
        
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

And it produces the following screen :
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jsbG.png)

What i expected was for the rectangles to go in the bottom right corner, stacked on one another, however nothing happens with ANY of the alignments i choose. And also why are they black? Shouldnt they be colored green/blue?

What i know is that a view chooses its own size and then aligns itself, the parent has no say in it, however here the parent has the alignment property which means it needs to be the one aligning child views. Theres clearly a gap in my logic and understanding, can anyone help me understand how exactly they work?

I tried doing the same with a VStack and an HStack but i got the same results with the exception of HStack where alignment .center aligned them next to each other

Comment: The color of the rectangles in an easy one: you color them with `.fill()`. `.background()` adds another view below the current one with the same size. Instead of `Rectangle().fill(Color.blue).frame(...)` you could also just use `Color.blue.frame(...)` – it comes out as a rectangle and saves on typing :)

Comment: Hint: put a `border` before your `frame` modifier and you'll see the size of the `ZStack`.

Comment: @jnpdx i added a border and the size is only surrounding the Rectangles! After the frame its the entire screen. I assume this means the Rectangles are only seeing the sizing of the ZStack BEFORE the framing happens and hence aligning themselves in the little space they have. But that begs the question, how to have the Rectangles see the size AFTER the framing. Embed within another zstack?

Comment: Regarding the size, here's what happens: the layout system just suggests sizes, but views decide on sizes themselves. There are some views (such as `Color`,  `Rectangle` or `GeometryReader`), that take as much space as the layout offers. There are other views that assume the size of the content (`Text` or `Image` would be good examples with some footnotes). ZStack is of the second kind. Another wrinkle is that .frame(...) just adds another view that suggests the size to the view it's applied to.

Comment: In effect, you have the ZStack, which has the size of the content (100x100), a "frame" view that has all the available size and then a "background" view, which takes all available size and paints a red rectangle in it.

Comment: Back to practical matters, you can change the size of the ZStack by adding something that assumes all available size inside of it. Something like: `ZStack (alignment: .bottomTrailing) { Color.red ...`

Comment: @Baglan Thank you so much! This makes things so much clearer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `fill` to set the color of `Shape`s. Just setting the `background` doesn't work, because the `fill` is black (an opaque color) by default, and hence will completely cover up the background you set.

As for why the rectangles are not at the bottom right, it is because the `ZStack` does not expand its size to fill the screen.

`.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)` doesn't do anything useful here. It merely removes the upper bounds of the size. For some views that "likes" to expand, this expands the view to fill its parent. But the size of the `ZStack` is determined by the sizes of the views in it. You only have two 100x100 views in it, so the `ZStack` is also 100x100.

To achieve your desired result, there needs to be some view in the `ZStack` that really wants to expand, which would in turn cause the `ZStack` to expand. For example, you can add `Color.clear` as the first view in the `ZStack`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack (alignment: .bottomTrailing) {
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(.red)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            Rectangle()
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
        }
        .background(.red)
        .frame(width: 300, height: 300)

    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).